# play button problem on my online radio listening site?

Tags: html

I have a problem with my online radio listening website.
my problem; When I turn on some radios to listen to them from a browser on the computer, the play button of the radio appears inactive and does not open. When I enter the same radio from Mabil phone with a web browser, it works without any problems. What could be causing this problem? I'm leaving my Radio.php page for you.

````
    <section id="clients">
        <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 mb-4 pb-4">
                    <div class="section-header">
                        <h2><?= $radio_sonuc['title'] ?> Dinle Canlı Dinle</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-zoom">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-12" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                                <a href="radio.php?id=<?= $radio_sonuc['id']  ?>">
                                    <div class="radio-component">
                                        <img src="https://www.myhomepage.com/radio3/images/<?= $radio_sonuc['image']  ?>" alt="">
                                        <span><?= $radio_sonuc['title']  ?></span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                             <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-12" style="padding-top: 15px;">
                                <audio controls preload="auto" style="width: 100%;">
                                    <source src="http://yayin.asymedya.com:8020/;" type="audio/ogg">
                                    <source src="http://yayin.asymedya.com:8020/;" type="audio/mpeg">
                                    <source src="http://yayin.asymedya.com:8020/;" type="audio/wav">
                                    <source src="http://yayin.asymedya.com:8020/;" type="audio/x-ogg">
                                    <source src="http://yayin.asymedya.com:8020/;" type="audio/acc">
                                    <source src="http://yayin.asymedya.com:8020/;" type="audio/x-wav">
                                    <source src="http://yayin.asymedya.com:8020/;" type="application/ogg">
                                    <source src="http://yayin.asymedya.com:8020/;" type="audio/opus">
                                    <source src="http://yayin.asymedya.com:8020/;" type="application/x-ogg">
                                    <source src="http://yayin.asymedya.com:8020/;" type="audio/x-vorbis+ogg">
                                    <source src="http://yayin.asymedya.com:8020/;" type="application/x-mpegURL">
                                </audio>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     ```
````

Comment: Please read the following link, with particular attention to the word Minimal... https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Are these the following links you said?

`<audio controls preload="auto" style="width: 100%;">
<source src="http://yayin.asymedya.com:8020/;" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="http://yayin.asymedya.com:8020/;" type="audio/mpeg">
<source src="http://yayin.asymedya.com:8020/;" type="audio/wav">
<source src="http://yayin.asymedya.com:8020/;" type="audio/x-ogg">
<source src="http://yayin.asymedya.com:8020/;" type="audio/acc">
<source src="http://yayin.asymedya.com:8020/;" type="audio/x-wav">`

Comment: I mean, debuig your site and isloate only the part that doesn't work, then edit away everything else from your question.  Everything else in the example should work, and so fucntion as a demonstration of your problem.  But spamming 100+ lines of php/html is not going to get you very far.